# Linq query for children class by Entity framework

Tags: linq, repository

I have a Employee,customer and customerSelectedCover class in my project.
employee class have a one-to-many relation to customer class and customer class have a one-to-many relation to customerSelectedCover.
also i created a repository for Employee in project.
in my project i get current employee by bellow code

```
var current = employeeRepository
    .FindBy(c => c.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
    .Single();
```

where is best way for retrieval all customerSelectedCover from db by current employee obj in linq query?

Comment: Use the `Include` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Include` method to get the collection of Customers and then use the `SelectMany` method to project all the CustomerSelectedCovers within all the customers of the given employee , consider the below sample code that simulates your need. ( the minimal properties are put for demo purposes)

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee CurrentEmployee = new Employee();
            List<CustomerSelectedCover> Covers = CurrentEmployee.Customers.
                                                                Include("CustomerSelectedCovers").
                                                                SelectMany(o => o.CustomerSelectedCovers).ToList();


        }
    }
    class Employee
    {
        public int Id;
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers;
    }

    class Customer
    {
        public int Id;
        public int EmployeeId;
        public DbSet<CustomerSelectedCover> CustomerSelectedCovers;

    }
    class CustomerSelectedCover
    {
        public int Id;
        public int CustomerId;
    }
```

Read more about `Include` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
and `SelectMany`[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)